# child input field with type="number" won't update after I edit it

Tags: jquery, html, input, numbers

I think I'm having an issue with 2 HTML5 input fields of type "number". What I'd like is that when I enter a number in the first field, that number appears multiplied by 2 in the second field.
My code works well until I modify the second field (either by typing a number or something else in the input field, or I click on the up/down arrows to modify the field value). Then, when I edit the first field, the second field isn't updated anymore.

Here's my code, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/6EnWT/

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="number" id="parent" />
    <input type="number" id="child" />
</form>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#parent').on('input', function () {
    $('#child').attr('value', $(this).val() * 2);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no, actually it's not. its working the first time because the 2nd input field is empty. if it's filled/changed it only writes an attribute value="xxx" but not changing the number at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's updating the attribute value. If you inspect your #child field you will see 10 if you enter 5 in the parent but inside the #child input the number you entered before will remain:

```
<input type="number" id="child" value="10">
```

You should use val() instead of attr('value' .. ) because thats updating the input field value instead of the attribute value.

Fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju5aT/)

JS:

```
$('#parent').on('input', function () {
  $('#child').val($(this).val() * 2);
});
```

E: The jQuery version in your fiddle is 1.8.3. That's why your fiddle is working. In your code its 1.11 and for that version you could use the code I provided

Comment: the difference is the old jquery version. OP is using 1.8 in his fiddle but 1.11 in his code